# Differences between behavior in user defined window.close function in Chrome and IE11

Tags: javascript, html, modal-dialog, window, internet-explorer-11

I am using jquery to open modal dialogs all over my application. When closing the dialog I use this piece of code.

```
if ($jdlg) window.close = function() { 
    if ($jdlg)
    { 
        $jdlg.dialogWindow.dialog('close');
        //$jdlg.frame.remove();
    } 
};
```

In Chrome this works, in IE11 it does not. I've read across different SO articles that this could have to do with IE setting different security zones, but after issuing the recommended steps like enabling protected mode, still nothing.

In the console, when I type window.close(), IE shows undefined, but window.close or in this case, parent.window.close the function appears, it just doesn't work when it is called.

Edit: Changed `window.close = function(){...}` to `closeDialog = function{...}` and it's working.

Comment: well `window.close()` is a built in method in the browser. Seems like a bad name to use.

Comment: I guess I could name it something else maybe?

Comment: I'll try something like ```closeDialog = function() { ... }```

Comment: Yeah that worked.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution to the issue. I suggest you post your solution as an answer for this thread and try to mark your own answer as an answer to this question after 48 hrs when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to rename `window.close = function(){...}` to `closeDialog = function{...}`